# Does the google spreadsheet API round off numbers when updating cell values?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

So I am trying to update values in a google sheets spreadsheet, and for some reason when I use the `spreadsheets.values.update` method, the value I'm trying to fill in gets rounded off.

**example**

```
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
value = [[myfunction(), 10, 123]]
body = {'values': value}
result = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                               range=RANGE_NAME,
                               valueInputOption='RAW',
                               body=body).execute()
```

Where `myfunction()` returns an integer. As an example, the integer used will be `1212650293435022848`.

The sheet *does* get updated, but the values filled in are

```
[1212650293435023000, 10, 123]
```

instead of

```
[1212650293435022848, 10, 123]
```

Is this a problem with my code or is it something from the API itself?

Comment: I believe that Google spreadsheets use doubles internally.   It does not support big integers.  I'm pretty sure this isn't your fault, and there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the info Frank! I'll probably wait for some other replies to be sure, but I'll work with that assumption in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Considerations

Big Integers are not currently supported in Google Spreadsheets. This is a limitation in its Number formats.

### Possible workaround

You could use Apps Script Custom Functions to work with Big Integers in a String format:

Thanks to the fact that Apps Script works with JavaScript you can parse strings into Big Integers using the BigInt() constructor.

### Reference

[Apps Script Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

[BigInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Answer (score 0):

BigInt also modifies a number like 6836735342561722374 to 6836735342561722368.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made it so the integer is converted into a string before I send it to the spreadsheet. This way there were no losses and I didn't have to use BigInt().